# Kivy/ Kivymd Map switch screens

Tags: python, dictionary, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I want to click a button which directs me to the map. Then when I click a button on the window of the map I want to go back to the beginning window https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxAr2.png

https://github.com/Mapquestions/map code is here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I cannot find any documentation to support this, I believe that you cannot define your root widget in an included `kv` file (at least I have not been able to get that to work).

So, your `main.kv` should look like this:

```
#:include binsmapview.kv

ScreenManager:
    Screen1:
    Screen2:
```

Then, your `binsmapview.kv` can be:

```
#:import MapView kivy.garden.mapview.MapView
#ScreenManager:  # does not work in included file
#    Screen1:
#    Screen2:

<Screen1>:
    name: 's1'  # corrected location of this line
    BinsMapView:
        lat: app.latitude
        lon: app.longitude
        zoom: 8
        on_zoom:
            self.zoom = 8 if self.zoom < 8 else self.zoom
        on_lat:
            self.start_getting_bins_in_fov()
        on_lon:
            self.start_getting_bins_in_fov()


        MDRaisedButton:

            text: "find closest bin"
            pos: root.width * 0.39, root.height * 0.1
            size: root.width * 0.25, root.height * 0.07
            md_bg_color: 102/255, 153/255, 255/255, 1
            halign: 'center'
            on_release: app.r()
<Screen2>:
    name: 's2'
    MDFloatLayout:

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "go to next page"
            pos: root.width * 0.39, root.height * 0.1
            size: root.width * 0.25, root.height * 0.07
            md_bg_color: 102/255, 153/255, 255/255, 1
            halign: 'center'
            on_release: root.manager.current='s1'  # added this to switch screens back
```

Comment: Thanks to your help I made some progress, now the issue is that the BinsMapView Class can't inherit from Screen and MapView at the same time and I need the class in the kivy file to be named BinsMapView, because the map won't show otherwise. If you want check the updated code. https://github.com/Mapquestions/map/tree/updated
Error: 'BinsMapView' object has no attribute 'manager' probably because isn't inheriting from Screen.

Comment: I think you just need to replace the `MDFloatLayout` in `Screen1` with `BinsMapView`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked a lot of respect to you.